# SIGABRT when running UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I created a new Swift file called GamePlayController.swift and I hooked it up to one of my Views in Storyboard. I am trying to run this code, but I get a SIGABRT at the line with the double asterisks. What is the reason for this?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GamePlayController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var scene: GameScene!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    **let skView = view as! SKView**
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false

    // Create and configure the scene.
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    // Present the scene.
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: Umm…you do know that the compiler is going to try to compile that, and that's not an acceptable statement in Swift?

Comment: I don't see what's unacceptable about that statement from the compilers perspective. The asterisks aren't part of the real source. The most likely case here is that the view contained in the view controller is not an SKView.

Comment: Oh, that's the reason why they're there. I was wondering how the compiler accepted that.

Comment: I was trying to bold the code to mark it as the line in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view` in this case is not an SKView instance. Try making an outlet in your source file to the SKView in the view controller in your storyboard. Google "iOS create storyboard outlet" if you're not sure how.